# Android game: Moving bitmap leaves blurry trail at ends

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-animation, game-development

I am trying to create a background scrolling for an Android game. Lets say it is a set of images moving at a speed.
To test out few basic elements, I have taken a small, rectangular image and moving it linearly from top to bottom. It moves but I see a small trail, like a rocket going in clouds(haha!). I tried various options in Paint() class to rectify this, but I couldn't.

I will first post a screen shot and then add relevant code.

[image]

So, here the vertical line is a single png image:

[image]

Now all I am doing is moving this bitmap from a certain (x,y) by increasing y by 5 at a time. It moves, but notice the ends of the image while moving. Sort of a trail, but not a permanent one. I have tried but unable to remove this effect. I tried on Samsung Galaxy S5. I didnot test on any other model.

The code:

The moving vertical image is a Sprite object:

```
package com.src.*.*;


import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;

public class Sprite {

    private Rect sourceRect;    // the rectangle to be drawn from the animation bitmap
    private int frameNr;        // number of frames in animation
    private int currentFrame;   // the current frame
    private long frameTicker;   // the time of the last frame update
    private int framePeriod;    // milliseconds between each frame (1000/fps)

    private int spriteWidth;    // the width of the sprite to calculate the cut out rectangle
    private int spriteHeight;   // the height of the sprite

    private int x;              // the X coordinate of the object (top left of the image)
    private int y;              // the Y coordinate of the object (top left of the image)
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private float degrees;
    private boolean rotate=false;
    private Matrix matrix;
    private Bitmap reversedBitmap;
    private Paint paint;

    public Sprite(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y, int fps, int frameCount) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        currentFrame = 0;
        frameNr = frameCount;
        spriteWidth = bitmap.getWidth() / frameCount;
        spriteHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        sourceRect = new Rect(0, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
        framePeriod = 1000 / fps;
        frameTicker = 0l;
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
                | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
        paint.setDither(true);
    }

    public void animate(){

    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setReverse(Bitmap reverse){
        this.reversedBitmap = reverse;
    }

    public void rorateSprite(float degrees){
        if(degrees == 0){
            rotate = false;
        }else{
            rotate = true;
        }
        this.degrees = degrees;
    }


        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            // where to draw the sprite
            Rect destRect = new Rect(getX(), getY(), getX() + spriteWidth, getY() + spriteHeight);

            if(rotate){
                canvas.drawBitmap(reversedBitmap, sourceRect, destRect, paint);
            }else{
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, sourceRect, destRect, paint);
            }
            }

        public void update(long gameTime){
            if (gameTime > frameTicker + framePeriod) {
                frameTicker = gameTime;
                //Log.i("INFO", "In if loop" + currentFrame + " framenr:" + frameNr);
                // increment the frame
                currentFrame++;
                if (currentFrame >= frameNr) {
                    currentFrame = 0;
                }
            }else{
                //Log.i("INFO", "in else" + currentFrame + "");
            }
            // define the rectangle to cut out sprite
            //Log.i("INFO", "sprite width: " + spriteWidth);
            this.sourceRect.left = currentFrame * spriteWidth;
            this.sourceRect.right = this.sourceRect.left + spriteWidth;

        }
}
```

The bitmap is setup as follows:
    `wallAnimation = new Sprite(resizedBitmapWall, 0, 0, 30, 1);` 
    `wallAnimation.setX(margin);`

The onDraw and Update for the sprite is as follows. It works without any exception or error. The only issue in all of this is the image having the blurry/tail effect at the ends. I dont even know the right word for it.

Code for onDraw and Update:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // fills the canvas with black
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    wallAnimation.draw(canvas);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(margin+laneWidth*i, 0, margin+laneWidth*i, laneHeight, paint);

    }
    canvas.drawText("High Score: "+ highScore, 10, 10, paint);


}

public void Update(long gameTime) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(wallState < laneHeight+laneHeight/6){
        wallAnimation.setY(wallState);
        //wallState+=laneHeight/80;
        wallState+=20;
    }else{
        wallState = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with paint.setAntiAlias(), setFilterBitmap() and 
setDither()?

Comment: Yes, I tried with 3 of them together. It didn't work. :(

Comment: Does it also happens without moving your sprite?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It happens at a certain speed. If you see the last piece of function I have mentioned, specifically this increment `wallState+=20;`. If I increment by 2, it is fine. As I increment by 3,4,5....20, the amount of blur increases.

Comment: I guess you need to call invalidate() while drawing so that it redraws. I am just guessing...